org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException:
JDBC exception executing SQL [select u1_0.id,u1_0.password,u1_0.username from user u1_0 where u1_0.username=?] [Table 'wheatherdb.user' doesn't exist] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]

I started writing a project added docker for work with DB, I connect a local DB and an error comes out. How to work with it locally or only if the docker picks it up inside themselves and connects to it. I know that it seems to be necessary for deploy, but during development?
docker-compose
version: '3.9'

services:
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DB: wheatherdb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    restart: always
    ports:
     - '3306'
    volumes:
    - wheatherdb:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  wheatherdb:
    driver: local

application.properties
spring.application.name=WeatherApp

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wheatherdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true

spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true

